# Hourly auto command for Discord

Tags: c#, timer, infinite-loop, discord, discord.net

I'm making a bot for discord and have little to no experience with c# coding. I got a basic structure going for basic commands but I can't implement an infinite looping timer which will run the command once every hour into the code. I've gotten far enough where the command works and is random I just cant get the hourly timer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace bleachedbot
{
class MyBot
{

    DiscordClient discord;
    CommandService commands;

    Random rand;

    string[] bestBleach;

    public MyBot()
    {

        rand = new Random();

        bestBleach = new string[]
            {
                //All images in the folder.
                "imagetests/Bleach 001.jpg",
                "imagetests/Bleach 002.jpg",
                "imagetests/Bleach 003.jpg"

            };

        discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
        {
            x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
            x.LogHandler = Log;
        });

        discord.UsingCommands(x =>
        {
            x.PrefixChar = '-';
            x.AllowMentionPrefix = true;
        });

        commands = discord.GetService<CommandService>();
        commands.CreateCommand("help")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("Commands: ");
            });

        RegiseterAutoBleachCommand();

        discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
        {
            await discord.Connect("<TOKEN>", TokenType.Bot);
        });
    }

    private void RegiseterAutoBleachCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("foldertest")
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {

                int randomHentaiIndex = rand.Next(bestBleach.Length);
                string bleachToPost = bestBleach[randomBleachIndex];
                await e.Channel.SendFile(bleachToPost);
            });
    }

    private void Log(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a timer you need to include system.threathing.
You can do this to add in the first lines:

```
using System.Threading;
```

After that you could use in your code the command Sleep.
Sleep will let your code pause for the seconds you choose.
Do it like this:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000) //This wil sleep for 5 seconds, because 5000 miliseconds = 5 seconds
```